# Android: Is View class appropriate for graphical elements?

Tags: android, graphics, view

We're designing an application that displays several hundred graphical elements on a single screen that need to respond to touch events and that can be animated -- however, they are not full-blown widgets (no focusing and other event handling). Is the `View` class appropriate for this, or is there a more lightweight class we should use?

(For those familiar with the Qt Framework, we're looking for something like the `QGraphicsItem` class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View` is just fine. It provides the full functionality and flexibility you may need to obtain graphical elements.